# Problemas com Posicionamento de Elementos HTML + CSS

Tags: css, posicionamento

Estou tendo muitos problemas em posicionamento de elementos no html+css, eu estou fazendo um site, e eu fiz um botão com animação lá, ai eu fui tentar colocar uma barra de navegação, ai eu coloquei antes do código do botão com animação, e também coloquei depois, a barra de navegação que eu estou tentando colocar sempre fica lado a lado com o botão, será porque? eu queria coolocar essa barra de navegação la em cima no topo do site, alguem sabe algum programa que eu possa fazer o positionamento de qualquer coisa tipo imagem, botão e deixar de qualquer posição que eu quiser, ou algum jeito de resolver o problema

Comment: Wilson, formule melhor a sua pergunta, inclua o código, um print ajudaria também... Formule uma pergunta onde os usuários possam ter uma noção do problema de forma verificável. Apenas um texto descrevendo o problema não ajuda nada. É preciso fazer uma pergunta clara onde os usuários possam visualizar o problema e poderem dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: pode deixar, vou fazer isso a proxima vez.

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta, não precisa fazer outra. Tem um link "editar" logo abaixo da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Wilson

Na verdade não tem um programa que crie isso, você só precisa imaginar a estrutura desse menu.

Vou te dar um exemplo genérico, quando você cria um menu, a estrutura dele é baseada em listas e ficaria assim:

```css
li {
 display:inline;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 margin-right: 0.5em;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> item 1 </li>
  <li> item 2 </li>
  <li> item 3 </li>
  <li> item 4 </li>
 </ul>
```

Clique em executar!
Com base nessa estrutura você colocaria o seu botão dentro de uma li, nem acima e nem abaixo. O restante você edita no CSS, caso um botão seja diferente você cria uma classe.

Não sei se isso já deu pra te dar uma ajuda, vou aguardar o retorno do seu print também.